# MasterDetailPage breaks when rendered as NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create an application with a navigation drawer. So each page should be accessible via drawer "link" item.

To protect those pages the application should only be accessible on a valid session otherwise the login page should be rendered.

**I'm trying to explain what I've done so far for reproduction purposes...**

After creating a new Xamarin forms project I created a MainPage holding the drawer and the currently rendered page

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        Master = new MasterPage();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new DummyPage()); // Set initial page
    }
}
```

So the MasterPage (drawer) is empty for now

```
internal class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {
        Title = "Master";
        Content = new StackLayout { Children = { } };
    }
}
```

Same for the rendered DummyPage

```
class DummyPage : ContentPage
{
    public DummyPage()
    {
        Title = "Dummy";
        Content = new StackLayout { Children = { new Label { Text = "Dummy Page" } } };
    }
}
```

So without a LoginPage my App file would look like

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

The rendered application then looks fine

[image]

When I try to render a LoginPage before accessing the main application part I would do something like

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Page initialPage;

        if (false) // check if logged in
        {
            initialPage = new LoginPage();
        }
        else
        {
            initialPage = new MainPage();
        }

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(initialPage);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the rendered MainPage then looks like

[image]

How can I fix that? What is missing or wrong?

---

**Update**
I found out that I can set the current displayed page globally. So for the start I do

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Page initialPage;

        if (isLoggedIn)
        {
            initialPage = new LoginPage();
        }
        else
        {
            initialPage = new MainPage();
        }

        MainPage = initialPage;
    }
```

and when clicking the "Sign In" button on the LoginPage I don't execute

```
SignInCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
});
```

This works for me

```
SignInCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage(false);
    }
}

public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage(bool value)
    {
        Master = new MasterPage();
        Detail = value ? new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) : new NavigationPage(new DummyPage());
    }
}
```

I think navigation doesn't add the main container.

Comment: yes, that would work but when I press the login button on the LoginPage, how can I redirect to the MainPage then? Currently I do `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());`

Comment: You write code in the main page for this logic. MainPage = new MainPage(); and if you loginPage, you write code this.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but what do you think about my updated solution? :)

Comment: I think when user signs in from application, you should rotate another page not exist main page. SignInCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new AnotherPage());
});

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you put the `MasterDetailPage` in a `NavigationPage` . Actually , it is nappropriate to do it . You could improve the code like following

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        if (false) // check if logged in
        {       
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(initialPage);
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, by doing so and when executing this on the login command `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());` the application renders false again

Comment: Call `Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage()` in command .